# Resizing UIBarButtonItem's Imageview so that the Image is Scaled Down (iOS)

Tags: ios, uiimage, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I have a button in my UIToolbar that I've assigned an image to, but I'd like for the image to automatically be scaled down (resizing the image outside of the app lowers some of its quality).

I attempted the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988918/change-width-of-a-uibarbuttonitem-in-a-uinavigationbar) which creates a custom imageView and then assigns it to the button. However, the image doesn't seem to be appearing. Here's my code:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"info.png"]];
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 35, 35);
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:imageView];
    self.tutorial_lbl = barButtonItem;
```

Note that if I comment out the last two lines and use the below line instead, the image does appear but then it loses the action of the button.

```
[self.tutorial_lbl setCustomView:imageView];
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I assume that adding a custom view does the same thing as when you use initWithCustomView: to create the bar button item. In that case, the docs say,

> The bar button item created by this method does not call the action
>   method of its target in response to user interactions. Instead, the
>   bar button item expects the specified custom view to handle any user
>   interactions and provide an appropriate response.

So, you should add a tap gesture recognizer to the image view, and set an action method for it,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 35, 35)];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"info.png"];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapper = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(barButtonTapped:)];
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapper];
    imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self.tutorial_lbl setCustomView:imageView];
}

-(void)barButtonTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender {
    NSLog(@"Tapped");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is awesome! One question--is this any way to make it so the button retains its "highlighted when tapped" attribute. Doing it like this turns the button into a static image (though the action does work).

Comment: @Kyle, I think you would have to implement that yourself also. You could do that by switching between two different images, one of which is dimmer than the other.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. I'll try that out!

Answer (score 2):

One thing you could try to do is set the image insets. Both `UIButton` and `UIBarButtonItem` support image insets. You do not need to add a `UIImageView` for this. Just set the image on your button and then set the image insets.

```
myButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(TOP, LEFT, BOTTOM, RIGHT);//UIButton

myBarButtonItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(TOP, LEFT, BOTTOM, RIGHT);//UIBarButtonItem
```

This resizes the images on the buttons. Positive values will decrease the size, while negative values will enlarge the image.

Comment: I tried this one out but couldn't get the left and right values to work. Though I'm able to resize the top and bottom values, the left and right remain stretched out no matter what value I use.

Comment: No. It seemed to work with iOS 6.x when I was working with it, but @rdelmar 's solution seems most elegant (and functional).

Answer (score 2):

I was able to achieve this by doing the following:

```
let originalImage = UIImage(named: "SearchIcon")
let scaledIcon = UIImage(CGImage: originalImage!.CGImage!, scale: 5, orientation: originalImage!.imageOrientation)
let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: scaledIcon, style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(MeViewController.showSearchUsers))
```