# Is it possible to resize the standard UIBarButtonItem style icons?

Tags: objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

I'm looking to reduce the size of the `UIBarButtonSystemItemStop` button style.  I've tried setting the width; however, that has no effect.

```
UIBarButtonItem *stopBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemStop target:self action:@selector(stopSearch:)];
```

I've tried changing `stopBarItem.width` but that doesn't seem to do anything.

I have done the obvious as in using a custom X icon, but there should be s simple way to reduce the size.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change width of a UIBarButtonItem in a UINavigationBar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988918/change-width-of-a-uibarbuttonitem-in-a-uinavigationbar)

Comment: use [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:YourImageView];

Comment: This then requires having a custom icon instead of using iOS's default icon.  I was hoping to just scale the system default X icon and not create my own.