# How do I change the width of the navigation bar item (specifically a button) in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4

I am trying to use a custom button on my navigation bar in Xcode, but the button inherits the default bar button item properties and adjusts its size according to those properties. I want to override the default  width. How do I do that?

I tried adding contents insets, but that did not change anything.[This is how the button appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B66LG.png)

Comment: Do you want custom frame?

Comment: That's thread will be help you: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988918/change-width-of-a-uibarbuttonitem-in-a-uinavigationbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988918/change-width-of-a-uibarbuttonitem-in-a-uinavigationbar)

Comment: @SagiShmuel I tried them, they did not work for me : (. I used a custom button, not the UI bar button.

Comment: @EmreCiftci sadly, no I do not.

Comment: Hi @JuliettePlange, you can set your custom button's imageView's `contentMode` like: `myCustomButton.imageView.contentMode = .aspectFit` for resize button's image.

Comment: Hi @JuliettePlange, I wrote the answer so that others can also benefit. If it works, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: @EmreCiftci done, but my reputation is less than 15, so it won't show.

Answer (score 1):

You should set your custom button's imageView's `contentMode` like:

```
myCustomButton.imageView.contentMode = .aspectFit
```

Enjoy